# Finding missing value in text file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting

I have a text file with following data.

```
 Name             Feature
 Marry            Lecturer
 Marry            Student
 Marry            Leader
 Bob              Lecturer
 Bob              Student
 Som              Student
```

I have only 3 features for every person i.e. *Lecturer*, *Student* and *Leader*.

The example above is just a sample and in my real data I have many more Persons having these features.

Now, I want to make a Unix script by which I can check that which of the 3 features is missing for respective person.

I understand that it can be done by making key value relationship, but I'm not able to figure it out correctly.

Im running `bash` shell on SunOS 5.10 i386.

Comment: Hint: `grep Lecturer file > lecturers`, `grep Student file > students` and the same with `Leader`. Then, `diff` these files.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so we don't give you the same solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the list of names in list.txt you can do:

```
for i in Student Leader Lecturer; do grep -F $i list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sort > $i.out ; done
```

To get the names in 3 separate sorted files, which you can compare with `diffuse` (or `xxdiff` or `diff3`):

```
diffuse *.out
```

If you just want to have files with the names of the persons missing each label, you can first generate a file with all names and use `uniq -u` to find the ones that are not in that list (the really unique ones):

```
sed -n '1!p' list.txt  | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sort -u > names.all
for i in Student Leader Lecturer; do fgrep $i list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1  | cat - names.all | sort | uniq -u > $i.missing ; done
```

If you want to do this from a script and a file `feature` with:

```
Leader 
Student
Lecturer
```

and the source table in `example.txt`, you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f *.missing names.all
feature=feature
sed -n '1!p' example.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sort -u > names.all
for i in $(cat $feature)
do
    fgrep $i example.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | cat - names.all | sort | uniq -u > $i.missing 
done
```

Comment: @user21546 I created this under `bash` you seem to be using `ksh` and you specified `bash` in your question.

Comment: if i use :    #!/usr/bin/env bash
 instead of #!/bin/ksh  , error is still there

Comment: @user21546 Please confirm that this solution works from the bash prompt. And accept this answer if it does. Then to make this into a bash/ksh script create a new question, referring to this one, copying the (working) lines and describing what you want to do (make a script) and what errors you get. Please don't create a moving target out of this post.

Comment: ok i managed to fix it somehow.
I can accept the answer , but im getting errors. 
grep -F is not working
Please help me to solve it and i will accept it

Comment: @user21546 what is the actual error that the grep line gives? And is this the line I posted, or the one from you script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18584/discussion-between-user21546-and-anthon).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in pure bash using arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Declare the various arrays we will be using
declare -A hasfeat;
declare -A names;
declare -A features;
## The input file
file="/path/to/file"

## The awk is used to skip the first line, the header
awk 'NR>1' "$file" |
    {
        while read name feat;
        do
            ## Save the names
            names[$name]=1;
            ## Save the features
            features[$feat]=1;
            ## Save this name/feature combination
            hasfeat[$name,$feat]=1;
        done
        ## For each name in the file
        for name in ${!names[@]}
        do
            ## For each feature in the file
            for feat in ${!features[@]}
            do
                ## Print the name if it doesn't have this feature
                [ -z ${array[$name,$feat]} ] && echo $name lacks $feat
            done
        done;
    }
```

Or, much more concisely, in Perl:

```
$ perl -lane 'if($.>1){$l{$F[1]}++;$k{$F[0]}{$F[1]}++}
  END{foreach $f (keys(%l)){ 
    map{print "$_ lacks $f" unless $k{$_}{$f}}keys(%k)
    }}' file
```