# Match missing values in text files

Tags: text-processing, scripting

Referring to this question :
   [Finding missing value in text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167306/finding-missing-value-in-text-file/167309#167309)

I have 2 files containing below data

example

```
Name             Feature
Marry            Lecturer
Marry            Student
Marry            Leader
Bob              Lecturer
Bob              Student
Som              Student
```

feature

```
 Lecturer
 Student
 Leader
```

I'm following below code to find missing feature against any name in example file :

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f *.missing names.all
feature=feature
sed -n '1!p' example.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sort -u > names.all
for i in $(cat $feature)
do
  fgrep $i example.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | cat - names.all | sort | uniq -u >  $i.missing 
done
```

This code gives me 3 different files, like lecturer.missing, student.missing and leader.missing and contains all the name which doesn't have this feature.

but I want the data to be in same file and output should be :

I need ouput like this :

```
Lecturer   Student   Leader
  Som                 bob
                      Som
```

I tried using appending the data in same file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please include everything needed to answer in your question. You can mention previous questions as background but each question should be able to stand alone.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, much better. Could you also clarify whether the header is part of the file? I mean, does the file actually contain `Name             Feature`? Also, please mention your OS in the question, not in a tag (and Solaris is not Linux by the way, why did you tag with both?).

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
awk '
  NR == FNR {feature[$1]=1; next} 
  $1 != "Name" {name[$1]=1; role[$1,$2]=1} 
  END {
    for (f in feature)
      printf "%-12s", f
    print ""
    for (n in name) { 
      for (f in feature) 
        printf "%-12s", (n SUBSEP f in role ? " " : n)
      print ""
    }
  }
' features roles
```

gives this output

```
Lecturer    Student     Leader      

                        Bob         
Som                     Som
```

close enough?

Comment: this is giving syntx error , m working on version SunOS adbuas03 5.10 Generic_150401-10 i86pc i386 i86pc–

Comment: Try with `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`

Answer (score 0):

All comments inside the text

```
awk '
  # make array with FEATURE elements from file "feature"
  FNR==NR{f[$1]=1;next}
  # collect to array all FEATUREs NAME by NAME
  FNR>1{e[$1]=e[$1]" "$2}
  # loop for each element in FEATURE array
  END{for (i in f) {
        # produce a head row with FEATURE elements
        r[0]=r[0] i" "
        # starts row counts for each FEATURE elements
        c=0
        # call all NAMEs 
        for (n in e)
          # check if the FEATURE do not exist for the NAME  
          if(e[n] !~ i){
            # produce next row number 
            ++c
            # construct apropriate row
            if(c in r)
              # if row exist add value to it
              r[c]=r[c] " " n
            else
              # if not exist put apropriate spaces before value
              r[c]=s n
            # find maximum row number between all FEATUREs
            if(c>l)
              l=c
          }
        # make shift in row for next FEATURE  
        s=s" "
      }
      # prints row by row
      for (k=0;k<=l;k++)
        print r[k]
  }' feature example | column -tn
```

Comment: this is giving syntx error , m working on version : SunOS adbuas03 5.10 Generic_150401-10 i86pc i386 i86pc–